# Close consumer connection to AMQP library in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amqp, node-amqplib

I use AMQP for my application. I want to close the connection to the consumer AMQP after all the message queues have been received. However, I don't know how to handle it. I will be very grateful and appreciated if someone help me. Thank you

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {

 var ok = ch.assertQueue('hello', {durable: false});

 ok = ok.then(function(_qok) {
  return ch.consume('hello', function(msg) {
    console.log(" [x] Received '%s'", msg.content.toString());
  }, {noAck: false});
});

return ok.then(function(_consumeOk) {
  console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C');
  
 });

 })
 }).catch(console.warn);
```

Answer (score 0):

`conn.close()` this close function will be close the connection